# Is there a way to create an ActionFilter that wraps the content of the Action in a using statement?

Tags: c#, async-await, asp.net-web-api, impersonation, action-filter

**My scenario:** My application is a Web Api 2 app using a business logic and repository layer for data access. The web application uses ASP.NET Impersonation to login to the database as the user accessing the website (authenticated via PKI). I have several async controller methods. However, when I `await` on the data access methods, the database call may complete on a different thread which will then access the database under the identity of my application pool which is not allowed to connect to the database.

**Example Controller**:

```
public class TestApiController : ApiController {
    private IBusinessLogicObject _myBlObject;

    public TestApiController(IBusinessLogicObject myBlObject){
        _myBlObject = myBlObject; //Populated through Unity
    }

    public async Task<int> CountMyJobs(string name){
        return await _myBlObject.CountMyJobsAsync(name);
    }
}
```

**Example Business Logic Class**:

```
public class BusinessLogicObject : IBusinessLogicObject
{
    private IGenericRepository<Job> _jobRepository;

    public BusinessLogicObject(IGenericRepository<Job> _jobRepository)
    {
        _jobRepository = jobRepository; //Populated with Unity
    }

    public Task<int> CountMyJobsAsync(string name)
    {
        using (WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Impersonate())
        {
            //JobRepository is effectively a DbSet<Job> and this call returns IQueryable<Job>
            return _jobRepository.Where(i => i.Name == name).CountAsync();
        }        
    }
}
```

If I move the `using` statement into the controller (wrapped around the await), it works fine.

The issue seems to be that because the `await` is outside of the impersonation context, it does not impersonate the database call (the `CountAsync()`) and I am unable to open a connection to my database.

**The Question**:

Is there a way I could write an `ActionFilter` or some other attribute on my controller method so that the method itself (containing the await call) would be automatically wrapped in the using statement?

Answer (score 2):

merpmerp's answer is going to be problematic in multi-threaded servers.  Since there is only one instance of an ActionFilterAttribute per decorated method, two simultaneous requests to the same method will result in *usingVariable* being overwritten, and only one will end up being disposed.

You'll need to take this a step further and store the ImpersonationContext somewhere in the request context-- e.g. in filterContext.Request.Properties.

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe there is a way to actually wrap a method in a using statement with an attribute, but you could essentially do the same thing by using the OnActionExecuting and OnResultExecuted methods in a custom ActionFilter.

```
public class IdentityImpersonateActionFilter : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    IDisposable usingVaribale;

    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        usingVaribale = WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Impersonate();
    }

    public override void OnResultExecuted(ResultExecutedContext filterContext)
    {
        usingVaribale.Dispose();
    }
}
```

Then you could decorate your methods or your whole controller class with `[IdentityImpersonate]`

```
[IdentityImpersonate]    
public Task<int> CountMyJobsAsync(string name)
{
    //JobRepository is effectively a DbSet<Job> and this call returns IQueryable<Job>
    return _jobRepository.Where(i => i.Name == name).CountAsync();  
}
```

You could also access this using variable in your function if you wish

```
public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
{
    usingVaribale = WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Impersonate();
    filterContext.ActionParameters.Add("parameterName", usingVaribale);
}
```

And add the parameter to your controller function

```
[IdentityImpersonate]    
public Task<int> CountMyJobsAsync(object parameterName, string name)
{
    //JobRepository is effectively a DbSet<Job> and this call returns IQueryable<Job>
    return _jobRepository.Where(i => i.Name == name).CountAsync();  
}
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep the impersonation the responsibility of the business logic, then you can just do this:

```
public async Task<int> CountMyJobsAsync(string name)
{
    using (WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Impersonate())
    {
        return await _jobRepository.Where(i => i.Name == name).CountAsync()
            .ConfigureAwait(false);
    }
}
```

Comment: What does the `.ConfigureAwait(false)` call do?

Comment: It's just avoiding the overhead of re-entering the ASP.NET request context until it's actually needed further up the stack.

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not fix the problem. It still executes the database call as the application pool identity and not as the impersonated identity.

Comment: Does it work if you use `Count` instead of `CountAsync`?